# How to avoid "cannot find -lR" for R Package installation on windows

Tags: r, windows

I want to install packages from source:

Setting up the environmental variables:

```
Sys.setenv(BINPREF = "C:/PROGRA~1/R/Rtools/mingw_64/bin/")
Sys.setenv(BINPREF64 = "C:/PROGRA~1/R/Rtools/mingw_64/bin/")
Sys.setenv(PATH = "C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-3.4.2/bin/x64/;C:/PROGRA~1/R/Rtools/bin/;C:/PROGRA~1/R/Rtools/mingw_64/bin/")
```

Installing any package from source results in "cannot find -lR" error:

```
install.packages("later")
```

**Error message:**

```
C:/PROGRA~1/R/Rtools/mingw_64/bin/g++ -shared -s -static-libgcc -o
later.dll tmp.def RcppExports.o callback_registry.o debug.o init.o
later.o later_posix.o later_win32.o timer_posix.o timestamp_unix.o
timestamp_win32.o tinycthread.o
-Ld:/Compiler/gcc-4.9.3/local330/lib/i386 -Ld:/Compiler/gcc-4.9.3/local330/lib -LC:/PROGRA~1/R/R-34~1.2/bin/i386 -lR C:/PROGRA~1/R/Rtools/mingw_64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.9.3/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe:
skipping incompatible C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-34~1.2/bin/i386/R.dll when searching for -lR
C:/PROGRA~1/R/Rtools/mingw_64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.9.3/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe:
skipping incompatible C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-34~1.2/bin/i386/R.dll when searching for -lR
C:/PROGRA~1/R/Rtools/mingw_64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.9.3/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe:
cannot find -lR collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status no DLL
was created
ERROR: compilation failed for package 'later'
```

As indicated here: https://community.rstudio.com/t/installing-source-package-failure-to-link/14775 it might be the case that for some reason a 32-bit file is linked on my 64-bit machine. But i dont see any Errors in my pathes.
(In the past, the install from source worked well).

```
Sys.info()
             sysname              release              version             nodename              machine                login                 user       effective_user 
           "Windows" "Server >= 2012 x64"         "build 9200"         "YY"             "x86-64"            "XX"            "XX"            "XX"
```

Session info:

```
Version:1.0 StartHTML:0000000107 EndHTML:0000001240 StartFragment:0000000127 EndFragment:0000001222
sessionInfo() R version 3.4.2 (2017-09-28) Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit) Running under: Windows Server >= 2012 x64 (build 9200)
```

Rstudio 1.1.383

Also posted here: https://community.rstudio.com/t/how-to-avoid-cannot-find-lr-for-r-package-installation-on-windows/49425.

Related:

- https://support.bioconductor.org/p/11509/ (But my sessionInfo does not Point to any Linux Version).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are making three mistakes:

1. You should not install rtools under `program files` or any other path with a space.
2. You are using `BINPREF` wrong, causing the 64-bit toolchain to be used on 32-bit.
3. The mingw gcc  dirs should **not** be on the PATH. Only the `bin` dir (`bash` and `make`) should be.

#### Recommended setup:

It is ***highly recommended*** to install rtools in the default location `C:\Rtools\`. This is the only configuration that is widely tested.

In this case you only need to make put `C:\Rtools\bin` is on the PATH in order to compile packages. R will automatically use the correct compilers on 32-bit and 64-bit.

#### With non-default Rtools location:

If you really must install rtools in a non standard location, you can set `BINPREF` to a pattern that includes `$(WIN)` that gets expanded to the correct path for example like so:

```
Sys.setenv(BINPREF="C:/YourRtoolsPath/mingw_$(WIN)/bin/")
```

When `make` invokes the compiler, `$(WIN)` gets substituted by either `32` or `64` which should then resolve to the correct path of the respective toolchain.

Comment: thank you very much!! For some strange reason `Sys.which("gcc.exe")` Returns `""`, but it still works. If i am not mistaken you probably mean `"C:/YourRtoolsPath/mingw_$(WIN)/bin/"`.

Comment: That is correct, gcc does not have to be on the PATH because there is a 32/64bit version. That is why R uses the BINPREF variable, to find the correct one.

Answer (score 0):

install [R](https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/windows/base/R-3.6.2-win.exe) version 3.6.2 with [rtools35](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/Rtools35.exe)
then when you install Rtools35 check yes on add rtools to system path
then  test with `later::later(function() {print("Got here!")}, 5)`
[image: later package test]

Comment: yes, r / rstudio/ rtools in General still works and was also properly working on my computer. In fact, on a similar Laptop it still does. So its Kind of a annoying Question because it is hard to reproduce,....sry for that.

Answer (score -1):

you have problem skipping R.dll , it cannot be linked.

try using another version of build tool-chain  maybe microsoft VC++ ((link.exe)) or try mingw32

are you able to compile any other package

pls try this test to see if there's any error

```
ccode <- 'extern "C" {void test() {double x=2.1; x = x+1;}}\n'
cat(file="R_Cpp_Test.cpp", ccode)
system("R CMD SHLIB R_Cpp_Test.cpp")
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. Do you mean VC++ or mingw32 as a replacement for rtools? Did you get that working with R?

Comment: did you use the last version of Rtools first

Comment: hi @ThanksGuys   i can install (later package) and build from source using [Rtools35](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/Rtools35.exe) and don't need to add path vars just when you install Rtools35 check yes on add rtools to system path     ,  that will install build tool path's properly     tested using R version 3.6.2